# Testing Firebase function with Jest - error : moduleName.split is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, jestjs

I am trying to test a Firebase Cloud function using the firebase-functions-test SDK... The documentation ( as often) is based on mocha/sinon, but as my project is based on Jest , I would like to use Jest instead...

In the doc , they state that as index.js is calling admin.initializeApp ... I need to stub it before importing my function.

so they write :

```
const test = require("firebase-functions-test");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
myFunctions = require('../index');
```

Using Jest , I tried to mimic it this way :

```
const test = require("firebase-functions-test");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
adminInitStub = jest.mock(admin, 'initializeApp');
myFunctions = require('../index');
```

but I get an error :

FAIL  tests/index.spec.js
      Cloud Functions
        ✕ encountered a declaration exceptioan (5ms)

```
  ● Cloud Functions › encountered a declaration exception

    TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function

      4 |
      5 | describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
    > 6 |   const adminInitStub = jest.mock(admin, "initializeApp");
        |                              ^
      7 |   const myFunctions = require('../index.js');
      8 |
      9 |   before(() => {

      at Resolver.resolveModuleFromDirIfExists (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:187:30)
      at Suite.mock (tests/index.spec.js:6:30)
```

where am I wrong ?

Comment: Did you find out why it had happened?

Answer (score 6):

The problem I think is misusage of the **jest.mock** function,

this function is to be used on a module, like 'require' or import for ex:

```
jest.mock('fs');
```

(https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)

you may be confusing it with **jest.fn** or **genMockFunction()**

Answer (score 2):

Instead `jest.mock(...)` use `jest.spyOn`. Like so:

```
adminStub = jest.spyOn(admin, "initializeApp");
```

More information on [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot point out exactly what you are doing wrong, I can point you to the Unit Testing Functions documentation for [firebase-functions-test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing). You can run through the example there or free preview [How to Test Firebase Cloud Functions With Jest](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/testing-cloud-functions-in-firebase/) lesson I found on AngularFirebase. I haven't tried this out as I don't develop in that environment, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Samuel... I read the example, as I mentioned it uses Mocha... and in the Angular one , it does not give any information on jest mocking..